# Django Rest Framework not updating ImageField with UpdateAPIView

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

All other fields are being correctly updated except the ImageField which also does not throw any errors. In the database I can see the image URL being updated, but on the file system there is no changes to the `media/` folder. When I use the model with `admin.site.register` everything works perfectly (hence I should have properly configured MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL) and I see file uploaded in the `media` folder.

`views.py`

```
class ProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def put(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        print(request.FILES)
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(p)
        serializer.update(p, request.data, request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def get(self, request):
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(p)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

`models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genderChoices = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    gender = models.CharField(choices=genderChoices, max_length=1)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
```

---

`serializers.py`

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName', 'dob', 'desc', 'gender', 'image', )
    
    #TODO: write validators
    def update(self, instance, validated_data, user):
        p = Profile.objects.filter(user=user)
        p.update(
            firstName=validated_data['firstName'],
            lastName=validated_data['lastName'],
            dob=validated_data['dob'],
            gender=validated_data['gender'],
            image=validated_data['image'],
        )
```

I am using Postman for testing and this is the response I get, with the image URL which is does not exist on visiting it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQyW2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `QuerySet.update` method to update your image. This method is intended for updating whole queryset. This method writes directly to the database, so it skips a lot of "magic" that normally happens in the background when you're invoking `Model.save` method. Especially, it skips all the file processing, including saving this file in `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. Use `Model.save` instead or handle saving the file in proper location manually.

Also, you don't have to fetch the user in this method, as your serializer was already invoked with profile as an argument, so it should be available in `self.instance` inside your update method.

Comment: Ah, got it. I had bit of a trouble the other day when I was trying to use `Profile.objects.get` with update method and read that it only works on QuerySet if I remember correctly. The other way is to manually do `p.field = value` and then `p.save()` right?

Comment: Yes, but DRF serializers should do all the work for you if you use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

install ==> **pip install Pillow**

in settings.py add :

```
import os

MEDIA_URL = "/media/" 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

in urls.py add:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in models.py add:

```
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images')
```

in apiview add **context={"request":request}**:

```
def get(self, request):
    p = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(p, context={"request":request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```